# How to Loop through controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've N generated checkboxes.

My checkbox are called "chkOption1", "chkOption2" ... "chkOption100"

How to loop through all that checkbox using a for ?

Example:

```
  for(int k=0; k< totalCheckBoxCount; k++) {
      // how to refer to the checkbox control ? 
  }
```

Comment: Does the form have a `Controls` collection?

Comment: It's not the same duplicate.. I wnat to know if it is possible to refer to a checkbox as "   Control["chkBoxOption" +k].isChecked  For instance

Comment: What happened when you tried it @stighy?

Comment: It´s really quite the same .... 1st comment: if you ask, you didn´t try. and yes, you can check this (you will have to cast to the correct type). and you will have to consider, that some controls are not on the form but in an container.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating them through code, create a `List<CheckBox>` as a `private` member of the form's class and hold reference to them in it. Whenever you want to iterate the checkboxes, you can make use of this list.

If these are created at design time, you can loop through the `Controls` collection of the control containing them. For instance, if they are directly placed on the form, use `this.Controls` (this can be omitted). If it is another container like a `Panel`, use `<panelName>.Controls`.